# Body not set with correct content height

Tags: javascript

I'm using object oriënted javascript and handlebars as templating system. 
Today I discovered a problem which I can't solve. When you use templates, they are loaded after the full DOM structure, a result is that the window and body don't get the right height. Concluding that my content is cut off at the bottom of the window and I don't get a scrollbar.
All elements (divs, forms, ...) are added via javascript. Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: I don't think you've given enough information. The body (etc) should dynamically resize to contain their contents, unless you have told them not to somewhere. How you add that content doesn't matter.

Comment: some code would be helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably in your css. Ensure that the rule for the element that should get a scroll bar does not have a line that reads:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

if it does change that line to

```
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: That was it, I had overflow hidden set on my body. Overflow auto solves the problem. Many thanks! I would never have found that.